# How can I upgrade to the latest Operator Lifecycle Manager on OpenShift 3.11?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, operator-lifecycle-manager

I've found version 0.6.0 of the Operator Framework's Operator Lifecycle Manager (OLM) to be lacking and see that 0.12.0 is available with lots of new updates. How can I upgrade to that version?

Also, what do I need to consider regarding this upgrade? Will I lose any integrations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that needs to be considered is that in OpenShift 3, OLM is running from a namespace called operator-lifecycle-manager. In future versions that becomes simply olm. Some things to consider,

- Do you have operators running right now and if you make this change will your catalog names change? This will need to be reflected in your subscriptions.
- Do you want to change any of the default install configuration?

  - Look into values.yaml to configure your OLM
  - Look into the yaml files in step 2 to and adjust if needed.

**1)** First, turn off OLM 0.6.0 or whatever version you might have.

You can delete that namespace, or as I did stopped the deployments within and scale the replicasets down to 0 pods which effectively turns OLM 0.6.0 off.

**2)** Install OLM 0.12.0

```
oc create -f https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/releases/download/0.12.0/crds.yaml
oc create -f https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/releases/download/0.12.0/olm.yaml
```

**alt 2)** If you'd rather just install the latest from the repo's master branch:

```
oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/master/deploy/upstream/quickstart/crds.yamlcrds.yaml
oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager/master/deploy/upstream/quickstart/olm.yaml
```

So now you have OLM 0.12.0 installed. You should be able to see in the logs that it picks up where 0.6.0 left off. You'll need to start learning about OperatorGroups though as that's new and going to start impacting your operation of operators pretty quick. The Cluster Console's ability to show your catalogs does seem to be lost, but you can still view that information through the commandline with `oc get packagemanifests`.